# Heat released by gas mixtures that undergo constant pressure cooling

Tags: mechanical-engineering, thermodynamics

I'm solving this problem, 
[image: Problem]

I used the formula $Q_p = mc_p\Delta T$. Since it is a mixture, I did this:
$Q_{Total} = 0.3 × 0.867 × (50-150) + 0.7 × 1.043 × (50-150 ) $ 
$ = -99.02 kJ/kg $
Is my solution and final answer correct? If not, where am I doing wrong? Thankss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assuming that both gases have the same mass, which isn't true.

$$\text{mass} = \text{density}\cdot\text{volume}$$

$V_{\text{CO}_2}=0.3 V_\text{total}$ and $V_{\text{N}_2}=0.7 V_\text{total}$

Use the calculated mass to find $Q_p$ unit is in $\text{KJ}/\text{m}^3$.